# AIDL method call + DeadObjectException freezes app indefinitely

Tags: java, android, aidl

I'm making a call to my AIDL service where I am supposed to login as a user in an app, something fails but it takes so long to tell me. Is there anyway I can have a certain amount of time before I timeout the attempt to communicate to show an error quicker? Here is the stack trace

```
E/MainActivity: doInBackground: 
            android.os.DeadObjectException
                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                at com.app IDbService$Stub$Proxy.query(IDbService.java:156)
                at com.otherApp.MainActivity$GetRecentRegisterActivity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:652)
                at com.otherApp.MainActivity$GetRecentRegisterActivity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:572)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/MainActivity: doInBackground: 
            android.os.DeadObjectException
                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                at com.app.IDbService$Stub$Proxy.query(IDbService.java:156)
                at com.otherApp.MainActivity$GetRecentRegisterActivity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:595)
                at com.otherApp.MainActivity$GetRecentRegisterActivity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:572)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: android.os.DeadObjectException
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
              at com.app.IDbService$Stub$Proxy.sendBugReport(IDbService.java:192)
              at com.otherApp.MainActivity$8.run(MainActivity.java:1028)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: android.os.DeadObjectException
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
              at com.app.IDbService$Stub$Proxy.sendBugReport(IDbService.java:192)
              at com.otherApp.MainActivity$8.run(MainActivity.java:1028)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Dead object error will come if your service is died.

Comment: @kiranBiradar yes but the thing is my app is freezing for 20 or so seconds. why is it freezing like that for so long?

Comment: Is it your own service?

Comment: @kiranBiradar yes

Comment: Can you show your service aidl interface? Also your application code where you are calling the service api.